# Verify Value exists in A Json Array with same key Names

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I have this json body

```
[
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "Name": "John",
        "Icon": "Icon/someplace",
        "SortOrder": 1
    },
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "Name": "Jessica",
        "Icon": "Icon/someplace",
        "SortOrder": 1
    },
    {
        "Id": 3,
        "Name": "Kevin",
        "Icon": "Icon/someplace",
        "SortOrder": 1
    },
    {
        "Id": 4,
        "Name": "Lint",
        "Icon": "Icon/someplace",
        "SortOrder": 1
    },
    {
       ...
    }
]
```

I am adding Values to the json via API, I need to verify that the new value is present is the json body

I am trying to Covert the response to json,

```
public object Get_Json()
{
    var response = GEt_Json_Body();
    var json_string = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response);
    JArray UpdatedContent = JArray.Parse(json_string);
    JObject Facility_Json = JObject.Parse(UpdatedContent[0].ToString());
    Assert.NotNull(Facility_Json);
    return Facility_Json;
}
```

This Only gives me back the first json:

```
{
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "John",
    "Icon": "Icon/someplace",
    "SortOrder": 1
}
```

`UpdatedContent[i]` i allows me to get the other jsons in the array, the problem is I don't know where the json I Created using the API will be placed, how to get All of the JArray and verify that my entry is there?

Update:

This is my Call:

```
public List<FooModel> Get_Json_Body()
{
    var request = new RestRequest();
    request.Resource = string.Format("/api/get_something");

    return Execute<FooMedl>(request, Endpoint);
}

public  class FooModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
}


public List<T> Execute<T>(RestRequest request, string Endpoint) where T : new()
{

    Client.BaseUrl = new Uri(Endpoint);

    var response = Client.Execute<List<T>>(request);

    Console.WriteLine(response.ResponseUri);

    if (response.ErrorException != null)
    {
        string message = String.Format("Error retrieving response: \n{0} \n{1}  \n{2}  ",
            response.Content, response.ErrorMessage, response.ErrorException);

        Console.WriteLine(message);

        var exception = new ApplicationException(message);
        throw exception;
    }
    return Response.Data;
}
```

**Update 2:**

The Answer By Davig G helped me to solve the problem, Was able to verify my input via

```
if(data.Any(f => f.Name == "Kevin"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Kevin exists in the data");
}
```

I am returing a List of dictionaries From Get_Json() method Using DavigG's answer I am able to verify and access the specific keys and values within the list.

Comment: what is your entry?

Comment: Why not deserialise to a concrete type that makes your C# code much easier to write and read?

Comment: Can you Deserialize to a List<Item>?

Comment: You have `response` that is an object. You then serialize that to a JSON string. Then you deserialize it to a `JArray`. What is the type of `response`, and why can't you get the data directly from that?

Comment: whenever it pushes a new entry get count value.

Comment: @HereticMonkey The response type is a `List <FooModel>`

Comment: I'm puzzle.. The new question does not match the answer. Only the first one does. But the first one is a duplicate. The answer doesn't answer the question  but is marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's much easier to deal with concrete classes than pure JSON objects, I would recommend deserialising your JSON directly into a list of objects like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
}
```

And the code to deserialise is:

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Foo>>(response);
```

Now you can treat that object as you wish, for example:

```
if(data.Any(f => f.Name == "Kevin"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Kevin exists in the data");
}
```

Or even make modifications:

```
var kevin = data.SingleOrDefault(f => f.Name == "Kevin");
if(kevin != null)
{
    kevin.SortOrder = 3;
}
```

And then if you need it to be back to the original JSON:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
```

Comment: No, you have now completely rewritten your question.

Comment: I have missed that I was deserialising my Json in the Execute method, Your answer helped me Thanks/